# How to refresh Sharepoint List Web Part in jquery?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, jquery

I had added one SharePoint list web part. I want to need refresh web parts  **without refreshing the whole page** using jquery or SharePoint default.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Online Modern List View Web Part doesn't provide function to auto refresh, currently, this is only available for classic view list view Web Part.

For this requirement, I would suggest you can submit a [User Voice](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/) to Microsoft for your convenience. It is a place for customers provide feedback about Microsoft SharePoint products.